# How can I use serde_json to deserialize arbitrary JSON into a Value-like object of raw bytes?

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I'm writing a library to deserialize a subset of JSON into predefined Python types.

I want to deserialize arbitrary JSON into an object that quacks like serde-json's `Value`. However, I don't want it to deserialize into `String`'s, `Number`'s and `Bool`'s - instead when the deserializer hits one of these I would prefer it simply keeps a reference to the respective byte string so I can efficiently (i.e. without the additional type conversion) parse the byte strings into the correct arbitrary Python types. Something like this:

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json::value::RawValue;
use serde_json::Map;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub enum MyValue<'a> {
    Null,
    Bytes(&'a RawValue),
    Array(Vec<MyValue<'a>>),
    Object(Map<String, MyValue<'a>>),
}
```

This will require writing a lot of traits so that it behaves like `Value`, and I'm not even sure if it won't just ignore deserializing the structural parts and put everything into a `RawValue`.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Json is a text-based protocol even if you store binary as json string in base64 encoding it would cost you twice the storage and network bandwidth.
I think you should have a look at bincode

Comment: @nikoss I just want to keep a reference to a slice of a JSON byte-string that is already in memory. There shouldn't be any copying as far as I am aware. Thanks, I'll check out bincode.

Comment: "This will require writing a lot of traits" I'm not sure that's true, you can probably implement `Deserialize` for `MyValue` (by hand, no deriving), try the 3 specific cases, then fallback on desertialising a RawValue (which should always work).

Comment: What do you mean by already in memory? if it's there already why do you need to parse it I think your question needs more clarification. Are you trying to intercept the memory of another process?

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks, I had considered this, but I was wary because I also want the interface that `Value` provides e.g. the indexing. Maybe this is the only way though.